# servlet mapping always 404 error

Tags: java, spring, servlets

This is this web.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-ap>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd">


        <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorial.ejemplospring" />

        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

</beans>
```

and this is the controller

```
package com.tutorial.ejemplospring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/main.html")
    public ModelAndView mainPage() {

        return new ModelAndView("main");
    }

}
```

I don't know why ´http:localhost:8080/ejemplospring/mail.html´ doesn't match with  the url pattern *.html?, I get a 404 error and if I try with / or /* I get the same error.

Comment: try get rid of ".html" in your `@RequestMapping("/main.html")`.

Comment: In the web.xml change the <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern> tag to <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncomment

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorial.ejemplospring" />
```

Seems that it is not finding the Controller and therefore not registering the Mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have your `ComponentScan` commented out? You need to enable this (uncomment), so it finds your `@Controller`

This

```
 <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorial.ejemplospring" />-->
```

needs to be:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorial.ejemplospring" />
```

Comment: Is uncomentad but still I have the same problem

Comment: Can you provide what views you have in this path? /WEB-INF/views/

Comment: main.jsp is the only view I have in /WEB-INF/views

Answer (score 0):

First issue is that you have to enable component scanning for the beans to be created.

Second one is that `Spring MVC` by default ignores the the extension in the URL, as it's to be used for specific purposes like `.json/.xml` would indicate to `Spring MVC` that you need data in `JSON or XML` format.

So your URL should be `mail.html.someExtension` ie. `mail.html.do`.

If you don't want to do that and you absolutely must have the extension as it is then you can use following configuration to enable extension mapping.

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Otherwise simplest way would be to just use some simple `URL` like `/mail` without any extension.